# Fail on deprecated messages thrown by requireActual

Tags: javascript, jestjs

In Jest, trying to fail tests when console messages printed during tests. Have been able to get this to work by changing `console.info`, `console.warn`, ... methods to throw error.

However, when using `jest.requireActual`, some warnings can show up which I'm not able to catch

package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jest": "29.7.0",
    "webpack": "5.88.2"
  }
}
```

example.test.js

```
describe("The test", ()=>{
    it("has a requireActual", ()=>{
        const x = {... jest.requireActual("webpack") }
        expect(typeof x).toBe('object')
    })
})
```

Output:

```
$ npm test 

> test
> jest

(node:26754) [DEP_WEBPACK_JAVASCRIPT_MODULES_PLUGIN] DeprecationWarning: webpack.JavascriptModulesPlugin has moved to webpack.javascript.JavascriptModulesPlugin
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:26754) [DEP_WEBPACK_LIBRARY_TEMPLATE_PLUGIN] DeprecationWarning: webpack.LibraryTemplatePlugin is deprecated and has been replaced by compilation.outputOptions.library or compilation.addEntry + passing a library option
(node:26754) [DEP_WEBPACK_SINGLE_ENTRY_PLUGIN] DeprecationWarning: SingleEntryPlugin was renamed to EntryPlugin
(node:26754) [DEP_WEBPACK_OPTIONS_DEFAULTER] DeprecationWarning: webpack.WebpackOptionsDefaulter is deprecated and has been replaced by webpack.config.getNormalizedWebpackOptions and webpack.config.applyWebpackOptionsDefaults


PASS  ./webpack.test.js
```

Ideally, I want some way to fail test when this warning shows up. If not possible, at least, to suppress the message.

I've tried:

- Changing implementation of console methods.
- Using Jest silent flag
- Also tried setting up Jest config with this npm package `jest-fail-on-console`

Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the flag the message suggests, you can see where the message is coming from:

```bash
$ node --trace-deprecation ./node_modules/.bin/jest
(node:31169) [DEP_WEBPACK_JAVASCRIPT_MODULES_PLUGIN] DeprecationWarning: webpack.JavascriptModulesPlugin has moved to webpack.javascript.JavascriptModulesPlugin
    at get JavascriptModulesPlugin (path/to/node_modules/webpack/lib/index.js:231:4)
    at Function.JavascriptModulesPlugin (path/to/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/memoize.js:22:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (path/to/example.test.js:4:15)
    at Promise.then.completed (path/to/node_modules/jest-circus/build/utils.js:298:28)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at callAsyncCircusFn (path/to/node_modules/jest-circus/build/utils.js:231:10)
    at _callCircusTest (path/to/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:316:40)
    at _runTest (path/to/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:252:3)
    at _runTestsForDescribeBlock (path/to/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:126:9)
    at _runTestsForDescribeBlock (path/to/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:121:9)
    at run (path/to/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:71:3)
    at runAndTransformResultsToJestFormat (path/to/node_modules/jest-circus/build/legacy-code-todo-rewrite/jestAdapterInit.js:122:21)
    at jestAdapter (path/to/node_modules/jest-circus/build/legacy-code-todo-rewrite/jestAdapter.js:79:19)
    at runTestInternal (path/to/node_modules/jest-runner/build/runTest.js:367:16)
    at runTest (path/to/node_modules/jest-runner/build/runTest.js:444:34)
(node:31169) [DEP_WEBPACK_LIBRARY_TEMPLATE_PLUGIN] DeprecationWarning: webpack.LibraryTemplatePlugin is deprecated and has been replaced by compilation.outputOptions.library or compilation.addEntry + passing a library option
    at get LibraryTemplatePlugin (path/to/node_modules/webpack/lib/index.js:241:4)
    at Function.LibraryTemplatePlugin (path/to/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/memoize.js:22:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (path/to/example.test.js:4:15)
    at Promise.then.completed (path/to/node_modules/jest-circus/build/utils.js:298:28)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at callAsyncCircusFn (path/to/node_modules/jest-circus/build/utils.js:231:10)
    at _callCircusTest (path/to/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:316:40)
    at _runTest (path/to/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:252:3)
    at _runTestsForDescribeBlock (path/to/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:126:9)
    at _runTestsForDescribeBlock (path/to/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:121:9)
    at run (path/to/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:71:3)
    at runAndTransformResultsToJestFormat (path/to/node_modules/jest-circus/build/legacy-code-todo-rewrite/jestAdapterInit.js:122:21)
    at jestAdapter (path/to/node_modules/jest-circus/build/legacy-code-todo-rewrite/jestAdapter.js:79:19)
    at runTestInternal (path/to/node_modules/jest-runner/build/runTest.js:367:16)
    at runTest (path/to/node_modules/jest-runner/build/runTest.js:444:34)
(node:31169) [DEP_WEBPACK_SINGLE_ENTRY_PLUGIN] DeprecationWarning: SingleEntryPlugin was renamed to EntryPlugin
    at get SingleEntryPlugin (path/to/node_modules/webpack/lib/index.js:296:4)
    at Function.SingleEntryPlugin (path/to/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/memoize.js:22:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (path/to/example.test.js:4:15)
    at Promise.then.completed (path/to/node_modules/jest-circus/build/utils.js:298:28)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at callAsyncCircusFn (path/to/node_modules/jest-circus/build/utils.js:231:10)
    at _callCircusTest (path/to/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:316:40)
    at _runTest (path/to/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:252:3)
    at _runTestsForDescribeBlock (path/to/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:126:9)
    at _runTestsForDescribeBlock (path/to/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:121:9)
    at run (path/to/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:71:3)
    at runAndTransformResultsToJestFormat (path/to/node_modules/jest-circus/build/legacy-code-todo-rewrite/jestAdapterInit.js:122:21)
    at jestAdapter (path/to/node_modules/jest-circus/build/legacy-code-todo-rewrite/jestAdapter.js:79:19)
    at runTestInternal (path/to/node_modules/jest-runner/build/runTest.js:367:16)
    at runTest (path/to/node_modules/jest-runner/build/runTest.js:444:34)
(node:31169) [DEP_WEBPACK_OPTIONS_DEFAULTER] DeprecationWarning: webpack.WebpackOptionsDefaulter is deprecated and has been replaced by webpack.config.getNormalizedWebpackOptions and webpack.config.applyWebpackOptionsDefaults
    at get WebpackOptionsDefaulter (path/to/node_modules/webpack/lib/index.js:324:4)
    at Function.WebpackOptionsDefaulter (path/to/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/memoize.js:22:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (path/to/example.test.js:4:15)
    at Promise.then.completed (path/to/node_modules/jest-circus/build/utils.js:298:28)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at callAsyncCircusFn (path/to/node_modules/jest-circus/build/utils.js:231:10)
    at _callCircusTest (path/to/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:316:40)
    at _runTest (path/to/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:252:3)
    at _runTestsForDescribeBlock (path/to/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:126:9)
    at _runTestsForDescribeBlock (path/to/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:121:9)
    at run (path/to/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:71:3)
    at runAndTransformResultsToJestFormat (path/to/node_modules/jest-circus/build/legacy-code-todo-rewrite/jestAdapterInit.js:122:21)
    at jestAdapter (path/to/node_modules/jest-circus/build/legacy-code-todo-rewrite/jestAdapter.js:79:19)
    at runTestInternal (path/to/node_modules/jest-runner/build/runTest.js:367:16)
    at runTest (path/to/node_modules/jest-runner/build/runTest.js:444:34)
PASS ./example.test.js
  The test
    ✓ has a requireActual (245 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.397 s, estimated 1 s
Ran all test suites.
```

As an example:

```js
    get JavascriptModulesPlugin() {
        return util.deprecate(
            () => require("./javascript/JavascriptModulesPlugin"),
            "webpack.JavascriptModulesPlugin has moved to webpack.javascript.JavascriptModulesPlugin",
            "DEP_WEBPACK_JAVASCRIPT_MODULES_PLUGIN"
        )();
    },
```

[`util.deprecate`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utildeprecatefn-msg-code) is a core Node.js API, hence the `(node:...)` prefix on the message. This is getting logged out at a lower level than the console Jest has access to, which is why the usual tricks (e.g. patching out the `console` methods, whether manually or via `jest-fail-on-console`) don't work. As those docs say, though:

> If either the `--no-deprecation` or `--no-warnings` command-line flags
> are used, or if the `process.noDeprecation` property is set to `true`
> prior to the first deprecation warning, the `util.deprecate()` method
> does nothing.

This gives one way to solve the problem, albeit suppressing *all* deprecations entirely:

```bash
$ node --no-deprecation ./node_modules/.bin/jest 
 PASS  ./example.test.js
  The test
    ✓ has a requireActual (193 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.328 s, estimated 1 s
Ran all test suites.
```

Alternatively, you can use `jest.mock` to replace even Node's own APIs, for example:

```js
jest.mock("util", () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual("util"),
    deprecate() {
        throw new Error("used something bad");
    },
}));
```

```bash
 FAIL  ./example.test.js
  The test
    ✕ has a requireActual (16 ms)

  ● The test › has a requireActual

    used something bad

      2 |     ...jest.requireActual("util"),
      3 |     deprecate() {
    > 4 |         throw new Error("used something bad");
        |               ^
      5 |     },
      6 | }));
```

I wouldn't necessarily *recommend* this, though; interfering with Node itself could lead to unexpected behaviour. Also `util.deprecate`'s behaviour is quite sensible - it only logs a given deprecation once, so you don't get overwhelming amounts of output. But this might be helpful in certain circumstances.